# Postgres Create Trigger Pass Parameter from Current Insert

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I'm very new to Postgres and right now I am tasked to create a trigger that would fire after an insert. Basically, I would let a script do an insert, fire the trigger that would grab a field from another table based on a parameter from the Insert Statement then update the newly inserted record with the value from the other table.

1. INSERT record to Table 1.

```sql
INSERT INTO "TableA" VALUES ('ABC-101', 'John Doe', '')

PersonID  |  Name  |  Address
------------------------------
ABC-101    John Doe
```

2. After this insert, I would then fire the trigger that would grab the value from a field in TableB.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_getaddress()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  PersonID     TEXT;
BEGIN
  PersonID  := TG_ARGV[0];

    UPDATE  "TableA" 
       SET  "Address"  = (SELECT  "Address" 
                            FROM  "TableB" 
                           WHERE  "PersonID" = PersonID);
    RETURN null;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_getaddress
AFTER INSERT
ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_getaddress(personid);
```

So basically, I have a field in TableB (say Address) that I need to grab in order to complete the record in TableA. I am using an ID to reference which Address to take from TableB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to pass a value to the trigger. A trigger has full access to all columns from the inserted row through the implicit record `new`.

You also don't need an `UPDATE` statement to change the inserted row. You just assign values to the fields in the `new` record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_getaddress()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
   l_address text;
BEGIN

   SELECT  "Address" 
     into l_address
   FROM  "TableB" 
   WHERE  "PersonID" = new."PersonID"

   new."Address" := l_address;
   RETURN new; --<<< important
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

You can't however change the inserted row in an `after` trigger, you need a `before` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_getaddress
  BEFORE INSERT --<<< important
  ON "TableA"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_getaddress(); --<< no parameter necessary
```

---

But copying data like that is usually a very bad idea. Why don't you just join the two tables if you need information from both?

---

<sup>Unrelated to your question, but you should *really* avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble then they are worth it</sup>